# Need a random ID for a div to solve a caching issue in Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, caching, random

I'm hoping someone can help a javascript noob with a caching problem. I'm making a site in Wordpress and I've got a caching plugin installed. I need one div (that's on the sidebar of every page) NOT to be cached as it contains an image and text that is randomly generated on each page load. I've done a lot of reading and testing out of various online solutions, but I can't get one to work. I read that the best way to get around this is to give the div a random ID via Date.now(), but I can't get that to work either. So I found something close, yet it, too, doesn't work (posted below). The div doesn't show on screen, yet its contents show up fine in my source code.

Can anyone fix it for me or suggest something? I am a complete noob when it comes to javascript. Thank you for reading! :)

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
function randomString(length) {
    var chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');

    if (! length) {
        length = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    }

    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        str += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
    }
    return str;
}

var randomId = "x" + randomString(8);
document.write('<div id="' + randomId + '">[autonav display="images,title, page, excerpt" pics_only="0" postid="11" attachment="1" orderby="rand" count=1]</div>'); 
</script>
```

Comment: What's the caching plugin you use?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I've tried WP Super Cache and I'm currently on W3 Total Cache.

Comment: About just using AJAX to get that div?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but if it's "How about using ajax?", I'm up for trying anything that might work :) I have no idea how to add ajax into a page though.

Comment: Can't you enclose your sidebar in your template with `<div id="rand-<?php echo rand(5,30); ?>">` ?

Comment: Ooh! Almost. The text and pic actually shows up now (thank you!), buuuut... when I reload the page and check the source code, I see it hassn't changed the "rand-5" div ID it's given my div, so the caching is still interfering. I thought having a unique div identifier meant no caching, from what I'd read...

Comment: Thinking about this... is there another way to go about it? Basically, no matter which page I click on, the sidebar widget displays the cached text and pic rather than a random one each time like it does when I disable the caching plugin. Surely there's another way to make the sidebar div not cacheable?